# Rendering properties of a map of objects in a table (or transforming (Key->String) to (Key->Html))

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I have a `Map<Key, ObjectWithProperties> data`.  We'll assume that `ObjectWithProperties` has two fields: `foo` and `bar`.

I want to render that in a table like so:

```
Field  |  Key1  |  Key 2 |  Key 3
-------+--------+--------+-------
foo    | Value1 | Value2 | Value3
bar    |   ...  |  ...   |  ...
```

Essentially, for each field in `ObjectWithProperties`, I want to output that value for each of the map entries.

I came up with this:

```
@**
 *  Renders a table row with the given label and data supplied by each object.
 *  @param label The row label.
 *  @param lookup The function that returns the required data as a String.
 *@
@renderRow(label: String, lookup: (Key => String)) = {
  <tr>
    <td>@label</td>
    @for(key <- data.keySet) {
      <td>
        @lookup(key)
      </td>
    }
  </tr>
}
```

And:

```
<tbody>
  @renderRow("Status", key => renderRow(data.get(key).status))
  @renderRow("Last update", key => renderRow(data.get(key).lastUpdate))
  ...
</tbody>
```

This works, but for some fields I want to take the field value and not just output a plain string, but some HTML markup (so I can add tooltips etc).  I came up with this:

```
@**
 *  Renders a table row with the given label and HTML supplied by each object.
 *  @param label The row label.
 *  @param lookup The function that returns the required data as a String.
 *@
@renderHtmlRow(label: String, lookup: (Key => Html)) = {
  <tr>
    <td>@label</td>
    @for(key <- data.keySet) {
      <td>
        @lookup(key)
      </td>
    }
  </tr>
}
```

and, for example:

```
@**
 *  Converts the given status to an nicely presented HTML representation.
 *  @param status The status.
 *  @return HTML content.
 *@
@statusHtml(status: Status) = @{
  Html(status match {
    case Status.SCHEDULED => """<span class="label label-success">Scheduled</span>"""
    case Status.COMPLETED => """<span class="label    label-info">Completed</span>"""
    case Status.CANCELLED => """<span class="label label-warning">Cancelled</span>"""
  })
}
```

and rendered as:

```
@renderHtmlRow("Status", key => statusHtml(data.get(key).status))
```

The problem is that I've repeated myself when it comes to `renderRow` and `renderHtmlRow` - these methods are identical expect for the fact that one accepts `(Key, String)` and the other accepts `(Key, Html)`.

Ideally, `renderRow` should just delegate to `renderHtmlRow`.  However, I'm not sure how to approach this.

How can I transform my `lookup: (Key -> String)` to a `(Key -> Html)` (and, in a way that still escapes characters).

(Alternatively, is there a better way?)

Comment: Try @Html(lookup(key))

Comment: @ajozwik: 1) Not sure exactly where you're suggesting I do that - are you suggesting to replace the body of the renderRow function with that call? 2) Calling HTML on a value will mean that '<' (and other HTML characters) are not escaped - that's the opposite of what I want for my non-HTML render function.

Comment: I would suggest essentially removing your `renderRow` helper entirely and only using the `renderHtmlRow` helper. To do this, you would need to escape your Html text that you want rendered as text before passing it in doing something like: `@renderHtmlRow("Status", key => SomeHtmlUtil.escapeHtml(data.get(key).status))` This would replace the call `@renderRow("Status", key => renderRow(data.get(key).status))` There are plenty of HTML escape utilities available to make this trivial to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does the trick (for Play 2.2):

```
@renderRow(label: String, lookup: (Key => BufferedContent[_])) = {
  <tr>
    <td>@label</td>
    @for(key <- data.keySet) {
      <td>@lookup(key)</td>
    }
  </tr>
}
```

and called like this:

```
@renderRow("Status", statusHtml(data.get(key).status))
```

Other text based entries are called like this (and will be properly HTML-escaped):

```
@renderRow("Status", Txt(data.get(key).foo))
```